# Problems installing maven2eclipse offline

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, installation, offline

I've been dealing with this problems for days now.

I need to install maven and the eclipse plug-in "maven2eclipse" on an offline environment.
So far I've installed maven on the computer but I'm not able to import or open a maven project in eclipse when I right click and select "import source" in the package/project explorer. Maven alternatives simply aren't there for me to use even though I've installed all of the plug-ins that m2e repository has to offer.

I've downloaded the m2e-repository for a local version with these commandlines:
Artifact and metadata (replacing .artifact. with .metadata. and running it again)
"C:\eclipse Java EE\eclipse.exe" -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication \ -source http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases \ -destination C:\Maven2Eclipse\repos

I then moved this local folder to the offline system and used it as a local repository.

I've also downloaded the helios repository, but I haven't installed anything from it. Becuase I seemed to be lacking some important dependancies without it. Something with eclipse.UI.. haven't been able to reproduce it.

Anyways, I've added the downloaded repositories to the disposal of my offline environment.
I installed everything with "m2e" and/or "maven" in it's name but I still can't import an "existing maven project". The option simply isn't there.

Here's a screenshot of what m2e software I have installed using the "install new software".
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzC3d.png

Have I missed something? There's something missing and keeping me from actually being able to select the import source "import an existing maven project".

I've been searching the web like crazy and I cannot find anything that resembles my problem.
There's quite a lot on mirroring eclipse repositories and what not but I don't seem to have a problem whit that, unless something didn't get downloaded.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you can update eclipse with the automatic update by using the url online directly.downloading and then installing the plugin manually causes a lot of issues as some plugins might not get downloaded properly in the installer or some plugins may be completely missing from the installer itself.

Please check the proper url to install the plugin automatically which matches with the version of the eclipse you may be using.

Answer (score 0):

Just...check this two things, if you go in eclipse configuration, inside the Maven tab?

1: Check the Offline mode...

2: Try to use the Maven you've installed (not the embedded one..)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by manually copying all plugins and feature files into their respective folders, making sure everything was installed as well and then restarting eclipse a couple of times with the -clean addition. After that, it started working.. weird :/

Thanks for the answers though!